# Multiple submits form and Ajax: Select which submit button is triggered

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, commerce

As I can't find a way to split a Drupal Commerce pane into several forms (so far it creates several field-sets) I had to create several submit buttons in the same form. But it's the same submit button that always gets triggered.

I have these 2 "forms":

```
- Field 1.1
- Field 1.2
-> Submit 1

- Field 2.1
->Submit 2
```

I believe this would not be a problem if I would not use ajax to submit the forms, but I do by using `'event' => 'click'` so that the form is submited when ENTER is pressed.

My problem is that if I press ENTER from the ***field 2.1*** it's the ***Submit 1*** that gets triggered.

**Any idea on how to select the right submit button with the click event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the Drupal click event:

```
'event' => 'click',
```

And to manually add it via jQuery by finding the next input button:

```
$('input.form-text', context).once('field_validation_keydown').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('input.ajax-processed').trigger('mousedown');
  }
});
```

But if anyone has a better solution, I'm curious to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

For every form element (button) add the `#name` property
and it should be unique in that form

e.g.

```
$form['button_1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#name' => 'button_1',
...

$form['submit_1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => 'submit_1',
...
```